# groovy, encodeBase64 is adding a character to the string

Tags: groovy

This is the output I was expecting:

```
echo test | base64
dGVzdAo=
echo dGVzdAo= | base64 --decode
test
```

But this is what groovy gives me:

```
def test = 'test'
print test.bytes.encodeBase64()
dGVzdA==
```

When I decode that I see:

```
echo dGVzdA== | base64 --decode
test%
```

How do I prevent encodeBase64() in groovy from doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the same.  `echo` adds a linebreak at the end. Doing the same things, will give you the same results.

```sh
 % echo -n test | base64
dGVzdA==
```

```
groovy:000> "test\n".bytes.encodeBase64()
===> dGVzdAo=
```